# mul_hi function in OpenCL: What does "high half" mean?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to debug a parallel program I have run in OpenCL where I got the code online. The functions I don't understand are `mul_hi` and `mad_hi`. The OpenCL specification itself is quite obscure as it says `mul_hi(a,b)` computes the high half of the product of a and b.

What do they mean by high half??

Thanks for your help
Amine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high half refers to the upper 16 bits of the 32-bit integer.
You can use the 4 bytes (or 2 halves) of an integer independently. This is done for ARGB colors for example with 4 bytes for alpha, red, green and blue shifted up 8 bits each.

```c
int high = ...; // 16-bit range
int low  = ...; // 16-bit range
int x = high<<16|(low&0xFF); // combine high and low: shift high 16 bits left, zero the upper 16 bits from low with bit mask 0xFF and combine the two with logical or
```

So `c=mul_hi(a,b);` computes `c=(a*b)>>16;`: `a` and `b` are multiplied and the high part of the result is shifted down and returned. `d=mad_hi(a,b,c);` is equivalent to `d=mul_hi(a,b)+c;`

Comment: Thanks @ProjectPhysX ! Makes much sense now

Answer (score 0):

`mul_hi(a,b)` computes the upper half of the double-width datatype computation of `a*b`. Meaning that it computes whatever overflows the original datatype.

As such:

```
char a = 16;                  // 0b0001'0000

assert(a*a == 0);             // 0b0001'0000 * 0b0001'0000 = 0b0000'0000

assert(mul_hi<char>(a,a)==1); // 0b0001'0000 * 0b0001'0000 
                              // = upper half of (0b0000'0001'0000'0000)
                              // = 0b0000'0001
```

Therefore for any type T, the range of possible outputted values by `mul_hi` is still the entire range of the datatype, not the range of the half datatype, as @ProjectPhysX suggests.